# How to populate GTK4 DropDown using a custom struct?

Tags: rust, gtk4

I'm using [gtk4-rs](https://gtk-rs.org/gtk4-rs/). I wanna use the following struct as item for a GTK4 dropdown.

```
pub struct SchemaItem {
    pub label: String,
    pub value: String
}
```

How can I do this? My understanding is that `DropDown` only supports `StringListModel` out of the box (just a simple array of strings), if you want something like the struct above, you need to implement `ListModel` and also provide an expression to read the values.

I can't find any real examples of this. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Your understanding is wrong `StringListModel` isn't the only supported one, any class that implements [`ListModel`](https://docs.gtk.org/gio/iface.ListModel.html) is supported. There is a [chapter on subclassing](https://gtk-rs.org/gtk4-rs/stable/latest/book/g_object_subclassing.html) in the documentation.

Comment: I'm not saying StringListModel is the only supported one, but it's the only one supported  automatically. So what I need is  a custom "class" which implements the ListModel interface. This seems to require a lot of code though (I mean, I just wanna use a simple label -> value pair, this should be builtin in). Anyway thx!

Comment: See that's just not true, there are [more classes that implement `ListModel` in gtk4](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/?q=class%3AListModel)

Comment: But I don't need any of the extra functionality they implement. I don't want a tree, sorting, mapping, filtering etc. There seem to be no documentation on a couple of things. The ListModel is just one part. In. order to create DropDown, I also need a store and an expression. Anyway I'll look into these, thx.